# mle esitimtate of dlm dlmModReg failed with"error code 11 from Lapack routine dgesdd"

Tags: r

I'm new to DLM. When I try to fit a dlm like that:

```
library(dlm)
bFun = function(xi) { dlmModReg(t, dV=exp(xi[1]), dW=exp(xi[2:(2+ncol(t))]));  
fit = dlmMLE(Y, parm=rep(0, 1+ncol(t)), build=bFun);
```

build the R studio just return errors like that

```
Error in dlmLL(y = y, mod = mod, debug = debug) :  
error code 11 from Lapack routine dgesdd
```

the EXP-data `t` {index by time } is:

```
2014-02-24       159       528         0         0         0         0       842       189         0         0          9042  
2014-03-03      1759      1305         0      4835         0        24      1952       549         0         0         10226  
2014-03-10      1719      1478         0       820      1096        66      1512       584         0         0         18561  
2014-03-17      1044      1009         0         2      2332       108      1387       635         0         0         25200  
2014-03-24       748      1437         0         0      2989       127      1468       696         0         0         29464  
2014-03-31       833      1210         0         0      2747       157      1397       462        13       821         34353  
2014-04-07       170       128         0      1451       387       236       176        31       156       190          2591  
2014-04-14       461       846         0      5000      1599       264      1214       260       476      1599         17408  
2014-04-21       547      1004         0      4858      2117       215      1345       330       539      1590         14693  
2014-04-28       381      1005      5890      1885      1710       203      1107       174       371      1250         13140  
2014-05-05       553       995      8752      1574       984       169       256        37       163      1358         11915  
2014-05-08       205       447        11       590       291        84        88         5       199       726          2495
```

---

and the obs data `Y` is:

```
2014-02-24  4891  
2014-03-03  6650  
2014-03-10 10972  
2014-03-17 13615  
2014-03-24 15358  
2014-03-31 17954  
2014-04-07  3418  
2014-04-14 10532  
2014-04-21  9711  
2014-04-28  7484  
2014-05-05  7503  
2014-05-08  1384
```